# How to check if a new window is loaded successfully?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have to access all the anchors on a specific div. Then, I have to assert if

1. the links are opened in a new window and
2. also make sure that the link is not broken.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following methods to verify if the links are opening a new window and are not broken. Code comments explains the code.

```
    public boolean xAnchors()
{
    String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle
    //      System.out.println(parentHandle);
    boolean isValidated = true;
    try{
        List<WebElement> anchors = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='container-with-shadow']//a")))); // This is an array of anchor elements
        try
        {
            for (WebElement anchor : anchors){                                 //Iterating with the anchor elements
                String anchorURL = anchor.getAttribute("href");
                anchor.click();
                String newWindow ="";
                for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
//                      System.out.println(winHandle);
                    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus to the new window
                    newWindow = winHandle;               //Saving the new window handle
                }
                //code to do something on new window
                if(newWindow == parentHandle)           //Checking if new window pop is actually displayed to the user.
                {
                    isValidated = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    boolean linkWorking = verifyLinkActive(anchorURL);      //Verifying if the link is Broken or not        
                    if(linkWorking)
                    {
                        System.out.println("The anchor opens a new window and the link is not broken");
                        isValidated = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("The anchor either does not open a new window or the link is broken");
                        isValidated = false;
                    }
                }
                driver.close(); // close newly opened window when done with it
                driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle); // switch back to the original window               
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            isValidated = false;

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("No Anchors founds on this page.");
        isValidated = true;
    }
    System.out.println(isValidated);
    return isValidated; 
}


public boolean verifyLinkActive(String linkUrl){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(linkUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        httpURLConnect.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        httpURLConnect.connect();
        if(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND){
            System.out.println(linkUrl+" - "+httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage()
                    + " - "+ HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use findbyelements to collect list of links. Put them into a loop and select a link. then use "getWindowHandle" to switch to new window where an assertion can be implemented that "Page Doesn;t exist" or some other error message not displayed. This will ensure whether a link is broken